# How do I get rid of the discolored off white border around this email?

Tags: html

Forgive my ignorance if this is an easy fix, but I don't work with HTML AT ALL, so please answer in very remedial terms :-)
Thanks so much for your help. 
I've been trying to learn HTML on the fly here to figure it out but am failing miserably

```css
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}
.body{
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
}
img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
display: none !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

#bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}

#templateContainer{
 max-width:600px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

h1{
 font-size:24px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h2{
 font-size:20px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h3{
 font-size:18px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h4{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

#templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */

#headerImage{
 height:auto !important;
 max-width:600px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

.headerContent{
 font-size:20px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.templateColumnContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}

.columnImage{
 height:auto !important;
 max-width:260px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

.leftColumnContent{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.rightColumnContent{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.footerContent{
 font-size:14px !important;
 line-height:115% !important;
}

.footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    
    <!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{Subject}}" />

    <title>{{Subject}}</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FAFAFA" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #FAFAFA; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FAFAFA; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" id="bodyCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; border-top-width: 4px; border-top-color: #dddddd; border-top-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 600px; border: 0px solid #dddddd;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templatePreheader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px;" valign="top"><a href="https://www.jove.com/?utm_source=joveemea&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=emea2019userengagement" style=" color: #cc5644;"><img alt="" border="0" height="40" src="http://info2.jove.com/l/283112/2017-04-18/r7gz/283112/11321/logo.png" style="width: 79px; height: 40px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="79"></a></td>
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;" valign="top" width="180">
         <div style="text-align: right;"><br>
         <a href="{{View_Online}}" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">View this email in your browser</a>.</div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END PREHEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END HEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr pardot-repeatable="" style="">
      <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-data="link-color:#00d369;" pardot-region="body_content00" style="color: rgb(3, 3, 3); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);" valign="top">
      <p>Dear Dr.&nbsp;{{Recipient.LastName}},</p>

      <p dir="ltr">We are producing a video methods collection focused on <a href="https://www.jove.com/methods-collections/104/preparation-of-acute-hippocampal-slices">Preparation of Acute Hippocampal Slices</a>&nbsp;led by&nbsp;Dr. Leroy&nbsp;at Columbia University.</p>

      <p dir="ltr">This online collection will serve as a comprehensive resource in the field for years to come and will set the standard for experimental research in the community.&nbsp;</p>

      <p dir="ltr">If you are interested in participating in building this resource by submitting an abstract, please let me know.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

      <p dir="ltr">Best Regards,<br>
      Ronald Myers, Ph.D.</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END HEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #30303c; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateBody" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody><!-- BEGIN COLUMNS // -->
       </tbody>
      </table>

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END COLUMNS --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateFooter" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="footerContent" pardot-data="link-color:#FFFFFF;" pardot-region="footer_content01" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0px 20px 20px; background: rgb(22, 104, 224);" valign="top">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="pd-table" style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td style="width: 19px;"><br>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://www.jove.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img alt="" border="0" height="35" src="http://storage.pardot.com/283112/3017/w_logo.png" style="width: 70px; height: 35px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="70"></a></span></td>
            <td style="width: 287px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;">© 2019. All rights reserved.<br>
            1 Alewife Center, Cambridge, MA 02140<br>
            ​​​​​​</span></span></span><br>
            &nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 59px;">
            <div style="text-align: right;"><br>
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://www.jove.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;">www.jove.com</a></span></span></div>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="footerContent original-only" pardot-data="link-color:#FFFFFF;" pardot-region="footer_content02" style="color: rgb(80, 80, 80); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0px 20px 20px; background: rgb(250, 250, 250);" valign="top">
         <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
         <span style="font-size:12px;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><a href="{{Unsubscribe}}" style=" font-weight: normal; text-decoration:underline;color:#1668E0;">Unsubscribe</a></span><br>
         <a href="https://www.jove.com/policies" style="color:#1668E0;">Policies</a></span></div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END FOOTER --></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!-- // END TEMPLATE --></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<!--
          This email was originally designed by the wonderful folks at MailChimp and remixed by Pardot.
          It is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0
        -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot, because I just plugged your code into codepen and got no border. If you're viewing this in your browser try a), clearing your cache, b) restarting, c) see how it looks in another browser.

Comment: @joshwcorbett No, it's definitely there.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't know what `off-white` border you're referring to, but as I said earlier... after plugging in your code I saw no border.

Comment: @joshwcorbett My code, no, because my answer removes it. In the question's code it's there though.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I used the question's code, I wouldn't plug in the answer's code to look for the problem.

Comment: @joshwcorbett But you said my code.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, the code mentioned in the question above. That is the code I plugged in to my editor and saw no border. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: @joshwcorbett The code in the question isn't mine.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Oh my bad, I got confused when your name was mentioned in the same vicinity of who asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's in 3 different places, and you have to remove them all:

```
<body bgcolor="#FAFAFA" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #FAFAFA; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FAFAFA; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" width="100%">
```

Remove `bgcolor="#FAFAFA"` and both occurrences of `background-color: #FAFAFA;` from there. Then it will be like this:

```css
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}
.body{
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
}
img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
display: none !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

#bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}

#templateContainer{
 max-width:600px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

h1{
 font-size:24px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h2{
 font-size:20px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h3{
 font-size:18px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

h4{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:100% !important;
}

#templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */

#headerImage{
 height:auto !important;
 max-width:600px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

.headerContent{
 font-size:20px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.templateColumnContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}

.columnImage{
 height:auto !important;
 max-width:260px !important;
 width:100% !important;
}

.leftColumnContent{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.rightColumnContent{
 font-size:16px !important;
 line-height:125% !important;
}

.footerContent{
 font-size:14px !important;
 line-height:115% !important;
}

.footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    
    <!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{Subject}}" />

    <title>{{Subject}}</title>
</head>

<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" id="bodyCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; border-top-width: 4px; border-top-color: #dddddd; border-top-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 600px; border: 0px solid #dddddd;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templatePreheader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px;" valign="top"><a href="https://www.jove.com/?utm_source=joveemea&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=emea2019userengagement" style=" color: #cc5644;"><img alt="" border="0" height="40" src="http://info2.jove.com/l/283112/2017-04-18/r7gz/283112/11321/logo.png" style="width: 79px; height: 40px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="79"></a></td>
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;" valign="top" width="180">
         <div style="text-align: right;"><br>
         <a href="{{View_Online}}" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">View this email in your browser</a>.</div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END PREHEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END HEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr pardot-repeatable="" style="">
      <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-data="link-color:#00d369;" pardot-region="body_content00" style="color: rgb(3, 3, 3); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);" valign="top">
      <p>Dear Dr.&nbsp;{{Recipient.LastName}},</p>

      <p dir="ltr">We are producing a video methods collection focused on <a href="https://www.jove.com/methods-collections/104/preparation-of-acute-hippocampal-slices">Preparation of Acute Hippocampal Slices</a>&nbsp;led by&nbsp;Dr. Leroy&nbsp;at Columbia University.</p>

      <p dir="ltr">This online collection will serve as a comprehensive resource in the field for years to come and will set the standard for experimental research in the community.&nbsp;</p>

      <p dir="ltr">If you are interested in participating in building this resource by submitting an abstract, please let me know.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

      <p dir="ltr">Best Regards,<br>
      Ronald Myers, Ph.D.</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END HEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #30303c; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateBody" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody><!-- BEGIN COLUMNS // -->
       </tbody>
      </table>

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END COLUMNS --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateFooter" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="footerContent" pardot-data="link-color:#FFFFFF;" pardot-region="footer_content01" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0px 20px 20px; background: rgb(22, 104, 224);" valign="top">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="pd-table" style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td style="width: 19px;"><br>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://www.jove.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img alt="" border="0" height="35" src="http://storage.pardot.com/283112/3017/w_logo.png" style="width: 70px; height: 35px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="70"></a></span></td>
            <td style="width: 287px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;">© 2019. All rights reserved.<br>
            1 Alewife Center, Cambridge, MA 02140<br>
            ​​​​​​</span></span></span><br>
            &nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 59px;">
            <div style="text-align: right;"><br>
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://www.jove.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;">www.jove.com</a></span></span></div>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
         <td align="left" class="footerContent original-only" pardot-data="link-color:#FFFFFF;" pardot-region="footer_content02" style="color: rgb(80, 80, 80); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0px 20px 20px; background: rgb(250, 250, 250);" valign="top">
         <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
         <span style="font-size:12px;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><a href="{{Unsubscribe}}" style=" font-weight: normal; text-decoration:underline;color:#1668E0;">Unsubscribe</a></span><br>
         <a href="https://www.jove.com/policies" style="color:#1668E0;">Policies</a></span></div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END FOOTER --></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!-- // END TEMPLATE --></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<!--
          This email was originally designed by the wonderful folks at MailChimp and remixed by Pardot.
          It is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0
        -->
</body>
</html>
```